# What's a theme that properly handles previews of different types of posts?

Tags: posts, categories, homepage

I would like to build a WordPress theme that displays customized previews of the latest posts from different categories on the site homepage.

For example:

- a video post would display a small video player
- a photo post would display a crop of the photo
- a text post would display the first few words of the post

(This would be styled to display in a grid, so an existing theme that does that would be a great starting point, but I don't think that's important.)

Is there a theme out there that implements this in the recommended way? I want to get this working in a WordPress-approved manner, so my hackery survives when I upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking at "different types of posts," you're looking at [post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats).  The format types are standardized in core (i.e. video, photo, default), but the presentation of these formats is 100% up to the theme.

That is, there is no "WordPress-approved manner" or standard for presenting previews of post formats.

There are, however, great examples of post formats in the wild:

- [Twenty Eleven](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/twentyeleven/), which ships with WordPress
- [Tapestry](http://www.studiopress.com/themes/tapestry) by StudioPress
- [Twenty Twelve](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/twenty-twelve-live-demo/) the new theme coming out with WP 3.5

If you need specific examples of *how* to implement differing presentations in your own theme, please feel free to [ask a new question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Oh, if only it were so. I am instead looking at a bunch of [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). All of my posts are "Standard" format.

I think this may deserve a more honest question, perhaps "how do I develop a theme for an existing WordPress site that's been heavily modified but poorly documented?" I just hope the answer is not "Give up."